# Initializing pointer of itself through the function c++

Tags: c++, pointers, access-violation

This is a class, and one of the variables of the class is a pointer that points to an object made from the same class. I want to make a reference to a child object(new Point object), but when I call a function getChild() from the main function it throws access violation reading location exception. It seems that creating a new Point object is no problem, but the pointer (*child) goes back to null when the function is executed. How can I keep the pointer from pointing back to null?

```
class Point {
private:
    double x;
    double y;
    Point *child;
public:
    Point(double a, double b){
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    Point getChild() {
        return *child;
    }
    void createChild(double a, double b) {
        child = new Point(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include the calling code

Comment: Are you sure you _create_ a child point **before** you try to _get_ it? You have no constructor in your class, so the `child` member has an undefined value initially. If you try to access a child object before `createChild()` creates it and properly initializes the pointer, you invoke an Undefined Behavior, which in this specific case results in access violation.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your observation which makes you think that   "the pointer (*child) goes back to null when the function is executed".

Comment: Just a side question: why should a `Point` have a child?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has multiple problems:

### Problem 1

You don't initialize `child` in the constructor, making every call to `getChild` before any call to `createChild` accessing "random" memory.

### Problem 2

You're creating a copy every time you call `getChild`, which might not be what you want and which makes handling of your `child` pointer hard (because that gets copied too -> who owns the pointed-to object now?)

### Problem 3

You don't check for `nullptr` in `getChild`

### Problem 4

You don't `delete` your old `child` in `createChild` (and you don't delete it in your destructor)

Comment: You can even extend problem 4 with the full [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)